# How does corona SDK build for Android

Tags: android, coronasdk

I recently read about Corona SDK and thought I willl give it a try, the concept is really cool since they use Lua as the scripting environment and it is good for cross platform development,

Lua script written can be directly run on the Corona Simulator since it is a Lua Interpreter

My question is How does it build for Android, does the Lua script get converted to Java code? Does this happen using the local android SDK or do I need to upload the code to Corona servers?

It will be really nice if someone who has used it give more details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my usage, this is how i understood it works :

- You upload your lua files to their server
- They package it with their interpreter for the given platform and the game engine
- They send you back your binary package

So the lua doesn't get converted to java code, it is just packaged

Comment: thanks, so u mean, they send back a apk file? (it must have .class  files in it right?), what if i need to make changes to AndroidManifest

Comment: yes an apk with a .class, some .so libraries and assets/resources you can tune your manifest (a little), some info can be found here: http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/configuring-projects

Comment: thanks that helped, so basically corona just does conversion of Lua to .java and then to .class files, So there is no need for a lua interpreter on the device to run the Lua compiled binary.